# Could we add a link to the site's FAQ when the site is proposed as an alternative in a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

It appears that the [tag wiki for career-development](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/career-development/info) on Stack Overflow directs people to *[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about)*:

> Career development questions are now considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.
>
> Progression of various titles and duties. Could be moving from Junior to Intermediate in a role or changing roles such as from Developer to Architect. Questions may involve background like education or experience and what to do next.
>
> **This subject is now considered off-topic for Stack Overflow; new career development questions should be asked on Programmers Stack Exchange instead.**

I edited the last paragraph to (emphasis showing the edit):

> This subject is now considered off-topic for Stack Overflow; new career development questions should be asked on Programmers Stack Exchange instead, **if they uniquely apply to programmers in general. Please read the [Programmers StackExchange FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) before asking.**

This [very recent question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130527/how-can-i-find-programming-work-in-south-america) got closed almost immediately, and I was surprised to find out that the OP was pointed to *Programmers* for a generic career advice question, as those are [mostly off topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Please make sure your question uniquely applies to programmers in general:
>
> [image]

Questions:

1. What other tag wikis point to *Programmers*? Is there an easy way I could find them myself?
2. Could we please make it a habit to point to the other site's FAQ, whenever we suggest it as an alternative on a tag wiki? (or in comments, etc)

---

The *Programmers* question is now deleted, so unless you have 10K rep there you'll just have to take my word for it :)

Or alternatively, check out this [Meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/is-there-anyway-to-recover-from-multiple-downvotes-on-an-off-topic-question), that refers to the same question.

---

Every reference to *Programmers* was removed from the [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) tag wiki, thanks @RobertHarvey. Although that's good enough for me, the deeper problem remains. If someone knows of another tag wiki pointing to *Programmers*, let me know...

Comment: +1 for the circular image thing

Comment: @Gabe [NickC](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143601/nickc) deserves [all the credit for that](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/resume-feedback/1616#1616)

Comment: The Tag Wiki has been edited several times now, each time making the P.SE suggestion more explicit. Perhaps the time has come to simply remove the suggestion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yay!

Comment: Oh my, there are over 850 open questions with that tag and I didn't see a single good one on the first page (by votes).  Is there a way to mass-close them?  I started flagging but gave up.