# Why are SO questions often closed rather than migrated?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow, I have noticed a tendency of moderators to close questions rather than migrating them to appropriate Stack Exchange sites (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938321/what-certification-can-i-get-software-engineers-developers). I believe this should be discouraged, because it forces the OP to write the entire question again. This attitude is exhibited less by other Stack Exchange site moderators. For example, on Programmers, if any code related question is posted, the moderators always migrate it, rather than closing. Is there any reason that this trend is not followed on SO?

Comment: For migration to happen 4 out of 5 close votes need to agree on the migration site. Just this would account for most questions not getting migrated (even when talking about questions that are migration candidates).

Comment: Because other sites complain when we [use them like toilets?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: ["The golden rule of question migration: never migrate crap!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/135615)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question is not constructive on Stack Overflow, then it's not constructive *everywhere*.

If the question you linked to ever appeared on Programmers, I'd vote to close asap.

If there is a trend of questions on Stack Overflow getting closed rather than migrated, well that's a good thing. Compared to every other site on the network, Stack Overflow is huge. It's more likely that 3K+ SOpedians are not aware of the specifics of other sites, than vice versa, so it's a good thing they vote to close instead of migrating.

You, on the other hand, are pretty active on P.SE. There is no reason at all not to flag those closed questions and ask for them to get migrated to P.SE. They are just closed, not deleted.

Comment: @yannis, I agree with the second part, that this **might** (I stressed on might, because I don't find anything wrong) not be suited to Programmers. But, first part is not correct. There are whole lot of questions posted on SO daily which are more appropriate to Programmers rather than SO. We can't treat SO as the parent site, which means if some post is not the children to this, then they won't find the parent on other SE site

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Read Mark Trapp's answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/mass-clean-up-of-career-development-questions, and my question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119369/could-we-add-a-link-to-the-sites-faq-when-the-site-is-proposed-as-an-alternativ

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Several SO questions that got migrated to P.SE where subsequently closed and some deleted. There is a mini plague of crap migrations, and we really don't want to further encourage that. Some good questions may be lost in the process, but c'est la vie. But if you are noticing a trend of questions getting closed instead of getting migrated, it might be because SOpedians finally heard our desperate cries...

Comment: @yannis, I have read those answers, they actually target the old question cleanup from SO to programmers. I am too against it. For newer question, SO moderators can surely migrate the question to appropriate site. Actually, my question is mainly concerned as to **Why the closing pattern is more Favorited here over the migration** On programmers, webmasters, dba, the questions(if suitable) are migrated rather than simply closed

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay I've updated the answer... Most 3k+ SOpedians are not very active on the smaller sites, and it's good they vote to close instead of migrating. They should only vote to migrate when they are pretty sure the questions won't die on the other site.

Comment: hmm....right on :-)

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Also please note that my meta question I linked above discusses _new_ questions. The question that sparked it appeared on Programmers less than a week ago, and it was closed, discussed on Meta, and deleted in a couple of days (or sooner). We don't only suffer from old questions, new ones get wrongly migrated all the time.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your premise is accurate (both the lack of migrations, and blaming mods for it). SO more than any other site adheres to the principle that 3k users should close posts, because SO has a large number of 3k users and so many posts that mods really don't have time to go through them all. SO has a migration path to Programmers, so regular users are capable of migrating there; it's their fault if they don't. The only posts that should be migrated are off-topic posts, and 9 of the last 10 off-topic closes on SO were done by users instead of mods. 4 of them were migrations, and the others were terrible, so at least from that limited sample things seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are many posts in Stackoverflow asking for full solutions instead of coding questions. I think that the moderators work is fine.

If the question is really about code, it must be migrated, I am agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Often questions are already a duplicate on the site they might be more suited to in which case I'll post a link to a possible duplicate in the comments before a plain "off-topic" vote to close.

A fair number of questions that might be candidates for SU or SF are too poorly specified to be a duplicate - there's just not enough details to figure out what they duplicate ought to be, they could be a duplicate of any one of 100 similar questions. These aren't worth migrating since they're probably be closed as NARQ as soon as they arrive without edits to fix the ambiguity.